# Intermittent Speech Failure in Multithreaded Python App Involving Pygame ElevenLabs and OpenAI

Tags: multithreading, streaming, chatbot, text-to-speech, openai-api

I'm working on a multi-threaded Python application that uses Pygame for audio playback and interfaces with several APIs (OpenAI, AssemblyAI, ElevenLabs) for text-to-speech and chat functionalities. The application functions correctly at times, but intermittently, it stops speaking sentences, and eventually, the audio output ceases altogether.

```
#Queue
transcript_queue = Queue()
msg_queue = Queue()
audio_buffer = Queue(maxsize=3)

# Global variables
order_counter = 0
order_lock = Lock()
fetched_audio = {}

def chat(conversation):
    response_accumulator = ""
    total = ""
    for resp in client.chat.completions.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=conversation, stream=True):
        content = resp.choices[0].delta.content
        try:
            response_accumulator += content
            total += content 
            # Check for sentence completion
            if re.search(r'[.!?]', content):
                # Split sentences on punctuation followed by space
                sentences = re.split(r'(?<=[.!?])\s', response_accumulator)

                for sentence in sentences[:-1]:
                    print(sentence.strip()) 
                    msg_queue.put(sentence.strip())
                response_accumulator = sentences[-1]  # Save last part for next chunk

            elif '\n' in content:  # Handle new lines as sentence boundaries
                sentences = response_accumulator.split('\n')
                
                for sentence in sentences[:-1]:  # Process complete sentences
                    print(sentence.strip())  
                    msg_queue.put(sentence.strip())
                response_accumulator = sentences[-1] 
        except:
            continue

    if response_accumulator.strip(): 
        print(response_accumulator.strip()) 
        msg_queue.put(response_accumulator.strip())

    # print("\n\nentire response:" , total)
    return total


#gets the voice back from ElevenLabs

def getvoice():
    # print("started getvoice")
    global elevenlabs_api
    global order_counter
    playback_thread = threading.Thread(target=play_audio_stream)
    playback_thread.start()

    while True:
        # print("started getvoice loop")
        sentence = msg_queue.get()
        if sentence is None: 
            audio_buffer.put(None)
            break
        
        drew ='t9pa8vZ7tCoTLCLirl6c'

        url = f"https://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/{drew}/stream?optimize_streaming_latency=3"

        headers = {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "xi-api-key": elevenlabs_api    #API key here
        }

        data = {
        "text": sentence,
        "model_id": "eleven_turbo_v2",
        "voice_settings": {
            "stability": 0.9,
            "similarity_boost": 0.8
        }
        }
        with order_lock:
            current_order = order_counter
            order_counter += 1
        fetch_thread = threading.Thread(target=fetch_audio_stream, args=(sentence, url, headers, data, current_order))
        fetch_thread.start()
        
    playback_thread.join()
    # print("ended getvoice")



def fetch_audio_stream(sentence, url, headers, data, order):
    # print("started fetch_audio_stream")
    global fetched_audio
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data, stream=True)
    response.raise_for_status()
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as tmp_file:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=5096):
            tmp_file.write(chunk)
        audio_file = tmp_file.name

    with order_lock:
        fetched_audio[order] = audio_file
        # Notify the playback thread that a new audio file is ready
        audio_buffer.put(order)
    # print("ended fetch_audio_stream")


#plays current audio stream
def play_audio_stream():
    # print("started play_audio_stream")
    next_to_play = 0
    while True:
        order = audio_buffer.get()
        if order is None:
            break

        # Wait until the audio file for the next order is fetched
        while order != next_to_play or order not in fetched_audio:
            audio_buffer.put(order)  # Re-queue the order
            order = audio_buffer.get()
            # time.sleep(0.1)  # Avoid busy waiting

        # Play the audio
        audio_file = fetched_audio.pop(next_to_play)
        pygame.mixer.music.load(audio_file)
        # print("\nStarting to speak...")
        pygame.mixer.music.play()


        while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
        # print("\nDone speaking.")

        os.remove(audio_file)
        next_to_play += 1
        # print("ended play_audio_stream")




# Conversation loop
def handle_conversation():
    # print("started handle_conversation")
    getvoice_thread = threading.Thread(target=getvoice)
    getvoice_thread.start()
    
    conversation = list()
    systemmsg = read_file('PhoneCallBot/system_msg.txt')
    conversation.append({'role': 'system', 'content': systemmsg})
    
    while True:
        transcript_result = input("\nUser: ")
        if transcript_result == "Exit":  # exit command
            break
        conversation.append({'role': 'user', 'content': transcript_result})
        response = chat(conversation)
        conversation.append({'role': 'assistant', 'content': response})
        # print("\nAI:", response, end="\r\n")
        

    msg_queue.put(None)
    getvoice_thread.join()

    

handle_conversation()
```

Behavior:
The application is supposed to process text through these APIs and play back the audio using Pygame with low latency. However, after some period of functioning normally, it randomly stops speaking the next sentence and then stops all audio output after.

Specific Question:
Could this intermittent failure be related to Pygame's handling of audio streams in a multi-threaded environment, or is it more likely an issue with the management of queues and thread synchronization? Any insights into how to debug such an intermittently occurring issue in a multi-threaded setup would be greatly appreciated.

Troubleshooting Done:

Tried to add print statements but once I do that everything fails.